# Compute Engine based on Docker image crashes after 30 minutes

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I've a custom Docker image based on 7.4-Apache that is being used for f1 instance type of compute engine. I successfully deployed and my website is reachable but after around 30 minutes or less the health check times out and then the container crashes.

I tried to see if there are any logs to investigate if this is an application issue or something else.

I wanted to ask are there any logs which I can see what's going on, if not how can I add logs?

Comment: Did you setup Stackdriver for your instance? https://www.jhanley.com/google-compute-stackdriver-logging-installation-setup-debugging/ and https://dertompson.com/2019/01/19/how-to-send-docker-logs-to-google-cloud-logging/

Answer (score 0):

**Since I don't know your exact configuration I can point you to some documentation at this point.**

First have a look at [Cloud Audit Logs documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit) - it describes how to view logs and find what you need. You will find more here about [viewing audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/logging/audit-logging).

Try looking for related logs in [logs viewer](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer).

Also have a look at [how to contruct query](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-queries#finding-quickly) to extract information you're looking for.

**If you provide more details about you congiguration I might be able to give a more precise answer.**